# Windows song banner API?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In Spotify and groove music on Windows 10, if a song is playing, it shows up with something like this:

[image: Screenshot (Not mine)]

Does Windows provide any sort of API to do that?

Comment: The magic search phrase is "system media transport controls."

Comment: poor old @DiegoMolina, posts that as an answer (which it is) and get shot down in flames for doing it

Comment: @pm100: What DiegoMolina posted was not an answer, but a "me too" comment.  Ironically, his comment contained more answer-worthy information (the name of the existing library he found) than the answer, although that by itself still isn't an answer, without at least a little explanation.